# How can I set a ComboBox initial DisplayMember to show the correct item depending on the ID taken from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, combobox

I wrote a Windows Forms application that gets all the data from a SQL Server.

The first form shows a `DataGridView` with `Receipts`, each receipt has its ID number, Name and `Status` which can be `Active` or `Paid`.

```
ID | Name      | Status
---+-----------+----------
1  | Receipt22 | Active
```

When a receipt is selected from the `DataGridView` and the "Edit" button is clicked, it will prompt the second form in which all the Items / Products are displayed for said receipt.

Now, my question is, I successfully filled the ComboBox with all the items from the Products table, but what I need to do. Is to set the initial DisplayMember of a row, to be that of an Item that has been selected.

So for example if "Receipt1" has Products "1,2,2,3,4,1" to it, it should display in each row, a ComboBox where the initial value member is equal to the ID of the Product.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHelper.ConString("Name")))
{
    SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Products", sqlCon);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sdr.Fill(dt);

    txtComboProducts.ValueMember = "ProductsID";
    txtComboProducts.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
    txtComboProducts.DataSource = dt;
}
```

This is how I fill the ComboBox itself, but I do not know how to show and add a row depending on the item that is in correspondence to the Receipt.

So, in this case where the items would be "1,2,2,3,4,1", let's say 1 = Water, 2 = Juice, 3 = Candy, 4 = Cake

```
Products(this is the comboBox) | Quantity |
-------------------------------+----------+
Water                                2        
Juice                                1        
Juice                                2       
Candy                                5 
Cake                                 1
Water                                4
```

and now if I would like to change let's say Row 1, I could just select the comboBox and change it to some other Product on the list.

The main problem is that, I do not know how to set the initial DisplayMember and how to add new Row for each of the items.

Does anyone have any ideas or advice? Would be appreciated.

Comment: The items come from the database, are stored in a (temp) datatable and mapped to the combo as a DataSOurce.  Therefore if you add an item to the database, if you refill the datatable, the new item will appear.  In that case, you might want to hold onto the datatable and dataadapter so you can simply refresh the data

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayMember` is the name of the field to display and will always stay the same (e.g. the product name).

You need at least three tables. A `Receipts` table, a `Products` table and a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) that assigns products to receipts. Let's call it `ReceiptProducts`.

Then to fill the combo box, you must execute query which goes like this

```sql
SELECT rp.ProductsID, p.ProductName
FROM
    ReceiptProducts rp
    INNER JOIN Products p
        ON rp.ProductsID = p.ProductsID
WHERE
    rp.ReceiptsID = 7  -- Assuming that this is the id of your current receipt
ORDER BY
    rp.Sorting
```

Tables:

- Receipts (PK ReceiptsID, ReceiptName, Description etc.)
- Products (PK ProductsID, ProductName)
- ReceiptProducts (PK ReceiptProductsID, FK ReceiptsID, FK ProductsID, Quantity, Unit, Sorting)

---

If you want to display different items in the combo box for each data grid row (this has nothing to do with `DisplayMember`), load the combo box items in the [DataGridView.RowEnter Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Seems I forgot to mention, I already made a ReceiptProducts table, that stores all that information. But once i access it and pull everything I need from it. I do not know how to actually sort it. 

That is, how to set the initial "display" to show, the items that are bought.

Comment: If the order is not by id or by name, add a column named `Sorting` containing the desired sort order and then add `ORDER BY Sorting` in your query. SortOrder: Water = 1, Juice = 2, Juice =3, Candy = 4 etc.

Comment: Probably you should display the receipt items in a related DataGridView in a Master/Detail view. Something like this [Walkthrough: Creating a Master/Detail Form Using Two Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews). Or use a specialized control [Master Detail Datagridview in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1215736/Master-Detail-Datagridview-in-Csharp).

Comment: I've updated my answer. The idea is (re)load the combo box items in the `RowEnter` event.

Answer (score -1):

```
DataTable dt;
void LoadC()
    {
        using (cnx = new SqlConnection("Var_Connection"))
        {
            cnx.Open();
            var adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Products", cnx);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "ProductsID";
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is the declaration of the datatable. declare the datatable outside the method as a class variable and then initialize the instance in the method of the button

example

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: just declare the datatable outside of the method. it must be declared as a class variable and then instantiated in the method (function)